# The items added multiple times into the RecyclerView with pagining

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination, adapter

I am working on android app with java. and now I have to do messaging activities. I use RecyclerView to display the messages items. Also my messages Api is work with pagining, every time I send the last id and the server return the previous 10 messages.(Page size is 10). For filling the RecyclerView I use an Adapter but my problem is, that the item is added multiple times into the RecyclerView.

I will put my activity code and the adapter code

### My Activity:

```
public class ConversationsActivity extends RootActivity implements ConversationsAdapter.ConversationOnClickHandler {


RetrofitBuilder rB = new RetrofitBuilder();
IApi service = rB.retrofit.create(IApi.class);
String authorization;
RecyclerView rv;
ConversationsAdapter adapter;
ProgressBar progressBar;

LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
//declare it as global var for future cancel refresh
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
boolean wasSwiped;


// initialise loading state
boolean mIsLoading,  mIsLastPage = false;

// amount of items you want to load per page
final int pageSize = 10;
int  mCurrentPage =0;
int lastId;
boolean f;
int p =1;


private AlphaAnimation buttonClick = new AlphaAnimation(1F, 0.7F);
int chatId, to;
String senderType, name, to_type;
TextView no_data;
Button btnActionBar11, send;
TextView tvActionBar;
EditText message;

Context context;

ArrayList<Conversation.Data> conversationArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversations);

    context = this;
    adapter = new ConversationsAdapter(this,context);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    chatId = intent.getIntExtra("chatId",0);

    Intent intent1 = getIntent();
    senderType = intent1.getStringExtra("senderType");

    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    name = intent2.getStringExtra("name");

    Intent intent3 = getIntent();
    to = intent3.getIntExtra("from",0);

    Intent intent4 = getIntent();
    to_type = intent4.getStringExtra("from_type");

    buttonClick.setDuration(500);
    authorization = checkAuthorization();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversations);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);

    tvActionBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvActionBar);
    tvActionBar.setText(name);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    adapter.setHasStableIds(true);

    // layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

    rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ConversationList);
    no_data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_data);
    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    btnActionBar11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActionBar11);

    btnActionBar11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(message.getText().length() > 0){
                sendMessage();
            }
        }
    });

    getConversation();

    rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            // number of visible items
            int visibleItemCount = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).getChildCount();
            // number of items in layout
            int totalItemCount = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).getItemCount();
            // the position of first visible item
            int firstVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            boolean isNotLoadingAndNotLastPage = !mIsLoading && !mIsLastPage;
            // flag if number of visible items is at the last
            boolean isAtLastItem = firstVisibleItemPosition + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount;
            // validate non negative values
            boolean isValidFirstItem = firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0;
            // validate total items are more than possible visible items
            boolean totalIsMoreThanVisible = totalItemCount >= pageSize;
            // flag to know whether to load more
            boolean shouldLoadMore = isValidFirstItem && isAtLastItem && totalIsMoreThanVisible && isNotLoadingAndNotLastPage;

            if (shouldLoadMore) loadMoreItems(false);

        }
    });

    Intent intent11 = getIntent();
    wasSwiped = intent11.getBooleanExtra("wasSwiped",false);
    //where you initialize your views:
    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);

    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            wasSwiped = true;
            //your method to refresh content
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ConversationsActivity.class)
                    .putExtra("chatId", chatId)
                    .putExtra("senderType", senderType)
                    .putExtra("name",name)
                    .putExtra("from", to)
                    .putExtra("from_type", to_type)
                    .putExtra("wasSwiped", wasSwiped);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


    if(wasSwiped){
        //don't forget to cancel refresh when work is done
        if(swipeLayout.isRefreshing()) {
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

    }


}

@Override
public void onClickConversation(Conversation.Data conversation) {

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void sendMessage(){


    Call<Message> call = service.sendMessage(authorization, to, to_type, message.getText().toString());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Message>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Message> call, Response<Message> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                if(response.body()!= null)
                    if(response.body().getData() != null);
                    message.setText("");
                    getConversation();
                 //
                //  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            } else {
                if(response.body()!= null)
                    if(response.body().getMessage() != null)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error: " + response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Message> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}

public void getConversation(){
    Call<Conversation> call = service.getConversation(authorization,chatId,"LANDLORD");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Conversation>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Conversation> call, Response<Conversation> response) {
            if(conversationArrayList != null)
                if(!conversationArrayList.isEmpty())
            conversationArrayList.clear();
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                if(response.body()!= null)
                    if(response.body().getData() != null)
                        if(response.body().getData().size() > 0){
                            if (!conversationArrayList.isEmpty())

                          conversationArrayList.clear(); //The list for update recycle view

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            for(int i =0; i < response.body().getData().size(); i++){
                                conversationArrayList.add(response.body().getData().get(i));
                                if( i == ( response.body().getData().size() -1 ))
                                    lastId = conversationArrayList.get(conversationArrayList.size() - 1).getId();
                            }
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            if (conversationArrayList.isEmpty()) {
                                rv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                no_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            else {
                                rv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                no_data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                configureRecyclerView(conversationArrayList);
                            }

                        } else {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            no_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            rv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error: " + response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Conversation> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
private void configureRecyclerView(ArrayList chat) {
    rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ConversationList);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


    adapter = new ConversationsAdapter(this,context);
    adapter.setConversationData(chat);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void loadMoreItems(boolean isFirstPage) {
    mIsLoading = true;
    f = isFirstPage;
    p = p +1;

    Call<Conversation> call = service.getConversationPagenation(authorization,chatId,senderType, lastId);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Conversation>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Conversation> call, Response<Conversation> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                if(response.body() != null)
                    if(response.body().getData()!= null) {

                      //  conversationArrayList.clear();
                        for(int i =0; i < response.body().getData().size(); i++){
                            conversationArrayList.add(response.body().getData().get(i));

                            if( i == ( response.body().getData().size() -1 ))
                                lastId = conversationArrayList.get(conversationArrayList.size() - 1).getId();
                        }

                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                        if(conversationArrayList == null){
                            rv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            no_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            return;
                        }

                        else if (!f) {
                            if (!conversationArrayList.isEmpty())


                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            adapter.addAll(conversationArrayList);
                      //      conversationArrayList.clear(); //The list for update recycle view


                        }
                        else {
                            rv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            no_data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            configureRecyclerView(conversationArrayList);



                        }

                        if(conversationArrayList.size() > 0)
                            lastId = conversationArrayList.get(conversationArrayList.size() - 1).getId();

                        mIsLoading = false;
                        mIsLastPage = mCurrentPage == lastId;
                        mCurrentPage = lastId;

                    }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Conversation> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("SomeActivity", t.getMessage());

        }
    });


}

public String checkAuthorization(){
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("log",0);
    return settings.getString("Authorization", null);
}
```

}

### My Adapter:

```
public class ConversationsAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ConversationsAdapter.ConversationsAdapterViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Conversation.Data> mConversation;
private ConversationsAdapter.ConversationOnClickHandler mConversationOnClickHandler;
private static SharedPreferences pref;


public ConversationsAdapter(ConversationsAdapter.ConversationOnClickHandler conversationOnClickHandler, Context _context) {
   mConversationOnClickHandler = conversationOnClickHandler;

    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences("log", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}


public void setConversationData(ArrayList<Conversation.Data> conversation) {
    mConversation = conversation;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}



public void addAll(ArrayList<Conversation.Data> newList) {
    int lastIndex = mConversation.size() - 1;
    mConversation.addAll(newList);
    notifyItemRangeInserted(lastIndex, newList.size());
}

@Override
public ConversationsAdapter.ConversationsAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    // Inflate the custom layout
    View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_msg, parent, false);

    // Return a new holder instance
    ConversationsAdapter.ConversationsAdapterViewHolder viewHolder = new ConversationsAdapter.ConversationsAdapterViewHolder(contactView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ConversationsAdapter.ConversationsAdapterViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Conversation.Data conversation = mConversation.get(position);
    TextView tv1 = viewHolder.tv1;
    TextView tv2 = viewHolder.tv2;

  //  SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("log", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String agentId = pref.getString("agentId", "");

    String from_type = conversation.getFromType();
    int from = conversation.getFrom();

    if((agentId.equals(String.valueOf(from))) && from_type.equals("AGENT")){
        tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv1.setText(conversation.getBody());
    }
    else {
        tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        tv2.setText(conversation.getBody());
    }

}

// Returns the total count of items in the list
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(mConversation == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    return mConversation.size();
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
    super.setHasStableIds(hasStableIds);
}

public class ConversationsAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public final TextView tv1;
    public final TextView tv2;




    public ConversationsAdapterViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMsgR);
        tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMsgL);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
       Conversation.Data selectedNotifiction = mConversation.get(position);
        mConversationOnClickHandler.onClickConversation(selectedNotifiction);
    }
}

public interface ConversationOnClickHandler {
    void onClickConversation(Conversation.Data conversation);

}


public long myTimeInMillis(String givenDateString ){
    //  String givenDateString = "Tue Apr 23 16:08:28 GMT+05:30 2013";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    long timeInMilliseconds = 0;
    try {
        Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
        timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
        //    System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return timeInMilliseconds;
}
```

}

any help or advice? 
And thankyou

Comment: For paging please visit this link: https://github.com/mirjalal/SIP-Task
I have implemented the paging with recycler view 2 month ago. Hope it will help you. If you will have question, please ask it without hesitation. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

in your addAll() function on ConversationsAdapter class

```
int lastIndex = mConversation.size() - 1;
mConversation.clear();
mConversation.addAll(newList);
notifyItemRangeInserted(lastIndex, newList.size());
```

this should do the trick

Comment: after I edited the addAll() as you say the recyclerView display the first page and when I try to scrool up all messages items are disapeer. @unownsp

Comment: does your newList have all data or only the new conversation?

Comment: all data. the pagining should get the older 10 messages when I scrolle up, same like messenger or whats app. so when I scrool up I need the pervious 10 items and the current items (conversationList.size + 10)

Comment: once i do paging...your newList has (10 old + 10 new) 20 data??

Comment: i rechecked your code....mConversation.addAll(newList); line indicates that you only add 20 data to your arrayList so, your code should work just fine....but check the paging response from the server...response from server may have same item multiple times

Comment: the response from the server work perfectly... i tested it via postman... :( any way.. thank u very much